# MySQL perform multiple, similar select queries with one statement

Tags: python, mysql, select, mysql-connector-python

I am currently using MySQL Connector/Python to query a database.

Currently, one of the processes I am doing looks something like this:

```
SELECT some_column FROM some_table WHERE some_column_2 = foo_1;
SELECT some_column FROM some_table WHERE some_column_2 = foo_2;
SELECT some_column FROM some_table WHERE some_column_2 = foo_3;
...
SELECT some_column FROM some_table WHERE some_column_2 = foo_9999;
SELECT some_column FROM some_table WHERE some_column_2 = foo_10000;
```

I am running a very large number of very similar queries.

The individual results of each query are important. Even if a given query yields nothing as its result.

Unfortunately, the current approach of making several thousand queries like so is time consuming and extremely inefficient.

So, my question is: is there any way to condense this procedure into a single query, so that it runs more efficiently?

I feel like this should definitely be possible in MySQL, and I'm fairly sure there's something I'm missing here.

---

So far, I have tried using MySQL Connector/Python's executemany() function, like so:

```
cursor.executemany("SELECT some_column FROM some_table WHERE some_column_2 = %s", foo_list)
```

I expected this to yield a list of the results to each individual query, but optimized as many queries. Unfortunately, this does not appear to work in MySQL Connector/Python, and results in a syntax error.

I am guessing that executemany is not meant to be used with SELECT statements, only with INSERT statements.

---

I have also searched the internet for ways to perform bulk select queries, but I have yet to find anything relevant to my situation.

I would like to explicitly point out that

```
SELECT some_column FROM some_table WHERE some_column_2 IN (foo_1, foo_2, foo_3, etc);
```

is *not* a valid solution, because it does not preserve the results (or lack thereof) from each individual query.

---

Any assistance with this would be welcome.

Comment: Yeah, something more efficient will be more efficient.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Why not fetch `some_column_2` as well with the single SELECT query and explicitly map the (using dict) "some_column_2" with the corresponding "some_column" ?

Comment: if you are saving the values of foo somewhere else in your DB, then you could treat this as a pivot table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than

> SELECT some_column FROM some_table WHERE some_column_2 IN (foo_1, foo_2, ..., foo_N);

simply ask for

```
SELECT some_column, some_column_2 FROM some_table WHERE some_column_2 IN (foo_1, foo_2, ..., foo_N);
```

The code generating the query knows about the foo 1..N values, and will see a subset of them coming back in the column 2 result.

As a separate matter, using `IN` often is an anti-pattern, which interferes with the mysql optimizer's ability to create a good plan. For a large `IN` clause, you may find you're better off going to the trouble of populating a `FOO` table, and joining against that.

Comment: I've decided to create a new table and use a JOIN statement. This seems to be the best available course of action. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction with that (I'm pretty new to MySQL).

Answer (score 0):

I've accepted J H's answer, because it gave the information I was looking for. However, I will also post this as a specific implementation of what they suggested:

```
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE foo_table (foo VARCHAR(20))")
insert_query = "INSERT INTO foo_table (foo) VALUES (%s)"
cursor.executemany(insert_query, foo_list)
select_query = "SELECT some_table.some_column FROM some_table RIGHT JOIN foo_table on some_table.foo = foo_table.foo GROUP BY 1"
cursor.execute(select_query)
```

This appears to work as intended.

EDIT: Because, for some reason, the cursor object in python MySQL Connector/Python will simply ommit "null" values, it is still necessary to pair "some_column" and "foo" values. Because, in my case, each "some_column" value is always completely unique to each "foo" value, I can use ANY_VALUE() to do this.

Comment: The `group by 1` is a little odd, I guess it works out to `group by some_column` which I was hoping had a unique index on it, or at least an index.

Comment: I strongly recommend adding a PK: `CREATE TABLE foo_table (foo VARCHAR(20) primary key)`. In general, every relation should have a primary key, even if it's a compound key spanning a few columns. For this particular JOIN, you really want the optimizer to exploit a unique index when determining which will be the driving table. Use EXPLAIN to verify your join clauses make sense. ( https://www.sitepoint.com/using-explain-to-write-better-mysql-queries/ )

Comment: Using a primary key is better in terms of optimization? Good to know, thank you. I'm not super familiar with MySQL.